# To use React, should I use nodejs (express)?

Tags: reactjs, web, webserver, frontend, web-frontend

I plan to build Web application for which the structure is:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is that correct structure in the commercial?
2. I plan that FrameWork of Frontend is express(nodejs) at first, but I try to change to django or flask because nodejs is my first use. I wonder if react can be used in this combination.

Comment: Which functionality do you need from the backend?

Comment: all functionalities login, user control, json data because I understand that the back-end server only delivers json data, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using firebase? You can handle authorization, store and retrieve data. I believe that it will be much easier than any other alternative.

[This](https://tighten.co/blog/react-101-part-4-firebase) great article will enable you to implement authentication in few hours. Handling data is also simple, I would use redux as well...

Comment: Do you mean to use the firebase as a backend?
In fact, since I am completely naive, to say the basics, does the term "frontend" refer to a static web server?

Comment: No. Front end refers to the web client which runs in the browser. A web server is one example for a back-end. Firebase can provide you the back-end services that i mentioned, without the bother of setting up and running a server. Highly recommended.

Comment: Read the 1st paragrpah of the following article: https://hackernoon.com/the-easiest-way-by-far-to-build-a-real-react-firebase-web-app-5dc6fa6f1b61

Comment: Pleasure. I hope that you didn't miss my recommendation to consider redux as well.